# deployed to heroku, can't see project in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I built a rails app and successfully deployed it to heroku

Now I would like to access the development version to make changes on my local machine

When I `rails s` I get the error:

`A server is already running. Check /home/username/myApp/tmp/pids/server.pid`

That file has one line that reads `2673`

What can I do to start the rails server while the app is hosted on heroku?

Answer (score 1):

```
 rm /home/username/myApp/tmp/pids/server.pid
```

Then

```
 rails s
```

If it is not working

If you want  to kill rails server process on port `3000` (which is what webrick normally uses), type this in your terminal to find out the PID of the process:

```
 $ lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

Then, use the number in the PID column to kill the process:

```
 $ kill -9 PID
```

Then

```
  rails s
```

Hope you will be able to run rails server again in your local m/c